Mappeo Springboot
Estoy haciendo una pagina web utilizando springboot y angula, es una tienda y lo que quiero hacer es el carrito, pero no se porque no se me crea este campo en la tabla de detallesOrden.
Yo quiero que la relación sea que en una orden pueden haber varios detalleOrden, pero un detalleOrden solo pertenece a una Orden 
Lo intentado poniendo OneToOne en la relacion de DetalleOrde. 
Clase DetalleOrden
package com.bolsadeideas.springboot.blueWaveSurf.app.model.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.ManyToOne;
import jakarta.persistence.OneToOne;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="detalles")
public class DetalleOrden implements Serializable{
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private Integer cantidad;
    private double precioUnidad;
    private double total;
    
    @ManyToOne
    private Orden orden;
    
    @ManyToOne
    private Producto producto;
    
    

    public DetalleOrden(Long id,  Producto producto,Orden orden, Integer cantidad, double precio, double total) {
        this.id = id;
        this.producto = producto;
        this.orden = orden;
        this.cantidad = cantidad;
        this.precioUnidad = precio;
        this.total = total;
        
    }


    public DetalleOrden() {
        
    }

    
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    
    public Integer getCantidad() {
        return cantidad;
    }

    public void setCantidad(Integer cantidad) {
        this.cantidad = cantidad;
    }

    public double getPrecio() {
        return precioUnidad;
    }

    public void setPrecio(double precio) {
        this.precioUnidad = precio;
    }

    public double getTotal() {
        return total;
    }

    public void setTotal(double total) {
        this.total = total;
    }

    public Orden getOrden() {
        return orden;
    }

    public void setOrden(Orden orden) {
        this.orden = orden;
    }

    public Producto getProducto() {
        return producto;
    }

    public void setProducto(Producto producto) {
        this.producto = producto;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "DetalleOrden [id=" + id + "cantidad=" + cantidad + ", precio=" + precioUnidad
                + ", total=" + total + ", orden=" + orden + ", producto=" + producto + "]";
    }
    
    
    
    
}


clase Orden
package com.bolsadeideas.springboot.blueWaveSurf.app.model.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

import jakarta.persistence.CascadeType;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.FetchType;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.ManyToOne;
import jakarta.persistence.OneToMany;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="ordenes")
public class Orden implements Serializable {
    

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private Date fechaCreacion;
    private double total;
    
    @ManyToOne
    private Usuario usuario;
    
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "orden")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<DetalleOrden> listaDetalles;
    



    public Orden(Long id, Date fechaCreacion, double total, Usuario usuario, Set<DetalleOrden> listaDetalles) {
        this.id = id;
        this.fechaCreacion = fechaCreacion;
        this.total = total;
        this.usuario = usuario;
        this.listaDetalles = listaDetalles;
    }

    public Orden(Date fechaCreacion, double total, Usuario usuario, Set<DetalleOrden> listaDetalles) {
        this.fechaCreacion = fechaCreacion;
        this.total = total;
        this.usuario = usuario;
        this.listaDetalles = listaDetalles;
    }

    public Orden() {

    }


    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }


    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public Date getFechaCreacion() {
        return fechaCreacion;
    }


    public void setFechaCreacion(Date fechaCreacion) {
        this.fechaCreacion = fechaCreacion;
    }

    public double getTotal() {
        return total;
    }


    public void setTotal(double total) {
        this.total = total;
    }


    public Usuario getUsuario() {
        return usuario;
    }


    public void setUsuario(Usuario usuario) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
    }

    public Set<DetalleOrden> getListaDetalles() {
        return listaDetalles;
    }

    public void setListaDetalles(Set<DetalleOrden> listaDetalles) {
        this.listaDetalles = listaDetalles;
    }


    

    

    


    
    
    
    
}


texto para que me deje subirlo(No se como subirlo sin tanto codigo)
sdaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaasssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss
